# SimpleWebRTC: consume video when peer machine has no webcam and microphone

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia

I am using SimpleWebRTC to create a video chat room application. 
One of the requirements is, a peer machine that has no microphone and webcam, should atleast be able to hear and see the video of other peers.
Is it possible to do?

I tried this using constraints{audio: false, video: false} in regular webRTC and it works on a machine that has no microphone and webcam.
How to accomplish this using simpleWebRTC?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `simpleWebRTC`. Even its creator says it does not fit all situations and makes broad assumptions about your app.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with simpleWebRTC, but I use PeerJS. To answer even if you don't have a webcam or mic, all I do is I answer with 'null' instead of the stream.

So in Peerjs instead of

```
call.answer(window.localStream);
```

you can say

```
call.answer(null);
```

Try to find the code in SimpleWebRTC where the call is made or answered and try this.